# Manage GPU settings like turn-off v-sync, antialiasing ant etc?

Tags: panel, settings, gpu

From the Nvidia X Server settings i have this:
https://copy.com/rB7ho3D0leoa

Not the GPU settings I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need the proprietary Nvidia drivers.
Go to `Software & Update -> Additional Drivers` and select the proprietary Nvidia drivers.
Then run `sudo nvidia-setings` from Terminal <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.

Comment: From where to download it?

Comment: You just need the proprietary Nvidia drivers and everything should be fine. I edited the answer.

Comment: I am using NVIDIA binary driver - version 331.8 from nvidia-331-updates(proprietary) and when type nvidia-settings in the terminal it opens Nvidia X Servers Settings.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using Xubuntu 14.04

Comment: There should be way more options in the nvidia settings. Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-settings`

Comment: The same thing.